# How to Print a SQLCMD variable in a database project?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database project for SQL Server 2016. In the project properties, SQLCMD Variables tab:

```
Variable: $(SOURCE)
Value: MyDB
```

All I want to do for now is PRINT that variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Test]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    PRINT [$(SOURCE)]

    RETURN 0
```

The project builds, I do a schema compare, then attempt to update and I get this error:

> The name "MyDB" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Is there a way I can print the SQLCMD variables I've set up when running a stored procedure?

Comment: Might be enough to use qoutes around...

Comment: OMG... you are right.  I had tried 
PRINT  '''' + [$(SOURCE)] + '''' which also failed.  But when I just now tried it this way it worked:  PRINT  '[$(SOURCE)]'        THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

I havent done much with this, but i have the following in one of my scripts and it works fine:

```
:setvar path "Variable"
PRINT '$(path)'
```

Comment: Double quotes to define the variable and single quotes for the print statement!  Thank you